# Why removeif() not available on streams of collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I see `removeif()` on `ArrayList`, but when I do `stream()` it there is no option of it. Is it because `removeif()` change the size of collection and stream needs a fix size to work upon ?

Comment: Because `removeIf` mutates the underlying collection. How would that even work on a general `Stream`?

Comment: "_Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities, have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast, streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing their source and the computational operations which will be performed in aggregate on that source_" – [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: The [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) also explains how streams are conceptually different from collections.

Answer (score 2):

to remove a element from a stream you can use `Stream::filter`. Example:

```
.filter(e -> e.getId() == 4)
```

> Is it because `removeif()` change the size of collection and stream needs a fix size to work upon ?

No, in fact stream can even work with a infinite number of objects

Answer (score 0):

Stream doesn't change source collection, stream take elements from sorce (it could be collection, infinite generator) then pass they through chain (transforming, filtering) on each step of mapping it will be a new objects, and then collect what passed in result (it could be collection, joined string or Integer) and return result in variable. It is provide declarative style and immutability, that can do great work in multithread calculations without side effect.